# Can I delete function for an rvalue version of object?

Tags: c++, c++17, c-strings, stdstring, rvalue

For legacy reasons, there's a lot of usage of `const char*` in the code I'm working on. I am trying to limit that, and stumbled on something I'd like to know. I have something like:

```
class AClass {
  public:
    const char* getValue() { return _value.c_str(); }
  private:
    std::string _value;
}
```

But this class now may be returned by copy, eg. by function:

```
AClass getAClass();
```

We also might wanna pass that to something like this:

```
void functionFromOtherLibrary(const char* value);
```

Now thinking about that, this might cause an error:

```
functionFromOtherLibrary(getAClass().getValue());
```

since the intermediate is eligible to be destroyed at that point. Even if the above goes OK, because it's one statement, this probably won't:

```
const char* str = getAClass().getValue();
functionFromOtherLibrary(str);
```

So I was thinking of writing something like:

```
class AClass {
  public:
    const char* getValue() { return _value.c_str(); }
    const char* getValue() && = delete;
}
```

to forbid calls for that method on rvalues. Just trying that gave me:

```
error C2560: cannot overload a member function with ref-qualifier with a member function without ref-qualifier
```

I'm not sure if this:

1. is valid construct and
2. is ever necessary. I've seen a lot of code that returns `const char*`s and it always seems to rely on the fact that the object returning the value will still exist and hold the source `std::string`.

I would really appreciate a more detailed explanation what happens when code uses `std::string`s to hold strings but only communicates with C strings.

<sup>And if you want to suggest removing C strings - that's what I'm trying to do right now. I still want an answer though.</sup>

Comment: Doing `const char* getValue() && = delete;` stops you from doing `functionFromOtherLibrary(getAClass().getValue());` which can be a perfectly valid use case.  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: @NathanOliver I wasn't 100% sure that it's actually valid. I must admit that after digging throug this I became less sure of everything than before. That's also why I asked for help.

Comment: Lets assume you have some function like `print(const char * str) { std::cout << str }`.  Doing `print(getAClass().getValue());` would be fine as the temporary is alive for the entire call to `print`.  Now, if `print` were to store the pointer for later use then it would be a problem since it would be a dangling pointer.  This is where you have to decide do you be restrictive and just say no temporaries allowed so you wont have UB, or it's harder to get it, or do you just state your contract and if the user ignores it, it's their problem.  I'm in the latter camp.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't overload a function with a ref-qualifier with a function without a ref-qualifier. The MSVC error text is nice and clear on this point.

But you can just add the ref-qualifier to the other one:

```
class AClass {
  public:
    const char* getValue() & { return _value.c_str(); }
    const char* getValue() && = delete;
};
```

Whether this is the right design or not is a separate question - but if you decide that it is, this is how you would do it.

Comment: So, the other function must be ref? Does that have any implications? Can ref, rvalue and value overloads all exist?

Comment: @TomášZato "You can't overload a function with a ref-qualifier with a function without a ref-qualifier. "

Comment: Ok, I admit that was a stupid question. What I really want to know is whether the ref overload will always act as the original unqualified one. I also hoped for more detail on correctness of this usage here.

Comment: @TomášZato The original accepts both lvalues and rvalues, as long as they aren't const. This version has two separate overloads, one only accepts lvalues and the other only accepts rvalues.